# Error consulta mysql con varibales php

Tags: php, mysql

Disculpen quisiera saber porque en mi consulta de mysql que realizo en php agregando 2 variables en mi **$query** no detecta la consulta después de **. $filtro.** , estuve buscando la falla pero no lo encuentro.
Alguien podría guiarme que puse mal :C

```php
$tiempo = trim($_POST['cod']);

$filtro = "";
if (isset($_POST['mes'])) {

    $fecha_inicio = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($_POST['mes']));
    $fecha_fin = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($_POST['mes']));

    $filtro = " AND t.date_created BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'";
}

$tiempos = " WHERE dias $tiempo";


$query = "SELECT resultado.id AS id, u.name AS nombre 
FROM (SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date(date_created), date(cust_33)) dias 
FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t 
WHERE is_active = 1 " . $filtro . ") resultado
JOIN wpam_psmsc_customers u ON u.id = resultado.customer " . $tiempos;
```

Comment: Prueba haciendo un echo de $query, copia la cadena resultante y valida algún cliente Mysql si la consulta de ejecuta de forma adecuada. Validando ese resultado puedes detectar el detalle que estés teniendo.

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: La consulta ya la tengo hecha con los datos que requiero y esta bien, ahorita hice un echo en el $query y no me imprimía las variables que quiero voy a checar eso

Comment: @VENEGASL Viendo la consulta te falta el campo `t.customer` en el subquery para que puedas hacer el JOIN, la sentencia quedaría  `SELECT t.id,t.customer,TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,DATE(... `

Answer (score -2):

Tu query esta mal escrita hasta donde se puede ver:

```
$query = "SELECT resultado.id AS id, 
                 u.name AS nombre 
          FROM (SELECT id, 
                       TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date(date_created), 
                       date(cust_33)) dias 
                FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t
                WHERE is_active = 1 " . $filtro . ") resultado
          JOIN wpam_psmsc_customers u ON u.id = resultado.customer " . $tiempos;
```

Acá vemos que es un `SELECT-FROM-JOIN` con una subconsulta dentro del `FROM`

La subconsulta si, esta mal en su sintaxis. Si vas a usar subconsultas, y asignaciones (t por ejemplo), usalas... (t.id y esas cosas)

Si empezamos por donde dices, `FILTRO`, como se supone que la unes en la SUBCONSULTA ?

```
SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date(date_created), date(cust_33)) dias 
FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t
WHERE is_active = 1 " . $filtro . "
```

Si `$filtro = "FILTRO";` 
El final quedaría algo como: `WHERE is_active = 1 FILTRO`

A menos que quieras que sea `WHERE is_active = 'FILTRO'`

Coméntame por acá si es asi.

Comment: Las variables los concateno dentro de la consulta, la variable filtro contiene esto " AND t.date_created BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'" , básicamente un pedazo mas de la consulta + unos datos obtenido por post

Comment: Por eso, esta mal concatenado, puedes imprimir la consulta por si sola, para mostrar los datos cargados ?? Usa var_dump($query) para que veas como se carga

Comment: string(414) "SELECT resultado.id, u.name as name FROM (SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date(date_created), date(cust_33)) as dias FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t WHERE is_active = 1 ) AS resultado JOIN wpam_psmsc_customers u ON u.id = resultado.customer WHERE dias                      esto es lo que imprime, pero al dar el boton para obtener los datos no se agregan

Comment: Ok tu consulta ahora es diferente de la original puesta en el Post. Ahora aparece ´´´AS resultado´´´, cuando antes no estaba. Pls actualiza esa info en la publicacion original tambien... De todos modos, el final de la consulta sigue incorrecto. Dice ´´´WHERE dias´´´